# Can you move the left toolbar in viewport?

Tags: interface

I'll be honest, I'm coming from using 3dsmax. So the fact that the tools are spread/copied in multiple locations is confusing. (and change sucks yaddayadda)

Been trying to emulate max more to make my transition a bit smoother, and had wanted to move the left tool bar so that it's horizontal instead of off to the side. Or even change the top bar from a drop down menu to tabs. I've always found drop down menus really annoying to work with, have a hard time selecting what I want to select without the menu disappearing. I like to be able to see my options instead of having to dig for them. :I

any help is appreciated, thanks for readin'.

Comment: My unsolicited advice would be to focus on the differences of the interface rather than trying to emulate a different software.  Transitioning to a bent interface will not help you. Each program has a certain logic built in and it is hard (and frustrating) to bend the workflow to work on a program that has a different one. You will need to build a new muscle memory, so it is better done from scratch. If you learn to use the software as is, you might become not only more flexible, but will find solutions that are innovative and might yield to a different kind of creativity...

Comment: There are pie menus for a lot of the more important options, you can enable those as an add-on.. search on 'pie'. The position of the toolbar may be awkward for you, but I would argue, although the journey may be gradual, if and when you become Blenderish, you won't be using the toolbar/dropdowns at all, so don't worry about them. Pretty much everything is a keyboard shortcut.. let your frustration prompt you to pick up the shortcuts, a few at a time. In Blender, If you think there must be a better way, there nearly always _is_ one.

Comment: Note that not all tools have a default keyboard shortcut, but it is quite easy to create your own.